# How to secure rest api with spring security when I have 2 types of users

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have two entities: teacher and student.
I would like to make some endpoints available only for teacher and some other for student.
I think that the easiest way is to use spring secure (or should I also use JWT ? )
But I'm not sure if I understand tutorial well. My idea :

Make two UserServiceDetails (TeacherServiceDetails which connects to Teacher JPA repository and same for student) and two classes that extend WebSecurityConfigureAdapter.
Is it enough? How can I set a ROLE for them? I didn't specify role in the table, can I hardcoded it? I`m not expecting any other users so Is it a good idea to implement it? :

```
private final String ROLE = "ROLE_TEACHER";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security would be just fine. By the way, it also supports the JWT token, but unless you are building a fullstack app with frontend at some other origin and a RESTful server, you don't necessarily need it. Spring Security form login will do.

Actually you dont't need two UserDetailsServices, you just have to make sure to set a Role for each User entity (and persist it along with the entity of course).

Then, your UserDetailsService would look like this:

```
public class SpringDataUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        User user = userService.findByUserName(username);
        if (user == null) {throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username); }
        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        user.getRoles().forEach(r ->
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.getName())));
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

Comment: oki think i understand. What if I want to use email instead of username ? Just change userService.findByUserName(username) to userService.findByEmail(email) ? It will automatically find method in JPA repository ? EDIT : what about userService ? Spring also can inject proper one (techer or student ) ?

Comment: Yes, just change the method's argument to `email` and do what you said, it would work just fine. Now about this `UserService`: I personally just use it to BCrypt the passwords. So my `UserServiceImpl` basically just has methods for finding entities (calls according repositories' methods) and for saving entities (calls according repositories' methods + BCrypts the passwords). In Spring a Service is a proxy between persistance layer and business logic.

Comment: In your case you'd have methods for both your Entities in your UserServiceImpl, eg. `saveTeacher`, `saveStudent`, etc... Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you so much ! I spend a lot of time looking for solution. Now i know what to do :D